# Bundle local JAR dependency within the target JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

My project structure is something like this.

`ProjectX` - depends on `ProjectY` which is a local JAR, added as a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.wow.projecty</groupId>
        <artifactId>projecty</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/Users/somepath/ProjectY.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Now, I'm creating a JAR for `ProjectX` with all the dependencies bundled in the JAR using this.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>ProjectXDriver</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is bundling all the dependencies from Maven but not the ones from local filesystem. In this case, classes from `ProjectY` are missing from the final JAR. (Also checked using `jar tf`)

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use a system scoped dependency? Is not built by a Maven/Gradle build?

Comment: It's a temporary thing, haven't set it up right now. But also curious about how to bundle system scope dependencies in the target JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix I found for this. Just install the JAR in the local maven repository and use it normally (without `system` scope / `systemPath`.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ProjectY.jar -DpomFile=../pom.xml
```